# In Vue.js, how do I unlink an array of radio buttons?

Tags: vue.js

With reference to the following Plunkr:

https://plnkr.co/edit/zbOBDEaWvn8Tw0F0O9cy?p=preview

The radio buttons are linked, because clicking 'Yes' checks both 'Yes' radio buttons, and checking 'No' checks both 'No' radio buttons.

In my data model, I have an array with two separate rows:

```
terms: [
  {termBoolean: 'Yes'},
  {termBoolean: 'No'}
]
```

How do I structure my code so that the rows are not linked, and I can check one 'Yes' and one 'No' at a time?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: My original answer was incorrect. Your problem is due to the version of Vue you're using, i.e. version 1.0.26. In version 1 of Vue, there was no `(term, index)` syntactic sugar. Instead, `index` was accessed via the special property `$index`. My earlier answer was not applicable for this version of Vue.

To fix your current code, please make the following change:

```
<template v-for="term in terms">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" value="Yes" v-model="terms[$index].termBoolean" />Yes
        <input type="radio" value="No" v-model="terms[$index].termBoolean" />No 
    </label><br>
</template>
```

Alternatively, upgrade to Vue 2.x. If you choose to go this route, please review the [migration guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html).

Comment: Came to the same conclusion after putting some debug code within the HTML `<pre>{{ terms | json }}</pre>`. Values were wrong and using `$index` looks cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <template v-for="(index, term) in terms">
```

EDIT :  think you misordered the index and the term.

Comment: Ordering of `(term, index)` was correct. The swapped order may work, but is semantically incorrect.

Comment: I just checked the documentary, and you are right, the index goes in the second parameter.

Comment: We were both approaching the problem wrong, though. That's for version 2 of Vue. The question is using version 1. There was no such index syntax, instead requiring the use of the special `$index` property provided by Vue.